# How to install libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel in ubuntu 18.04 hp laptop ay503tx

Tags: 18.04, rtl8723be

ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
wifi driver rtl8723be

i ran this commands in the terminal

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
git checkout extended
sudo make install

make command not found :
```

then i ran

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall make
 sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

error:

```
 sudo make install
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/build M=/home/rizwan/Downloads/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic'
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CC [M]  /home/rizwan/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/base.o
cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/rizwan/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/base.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/rizwan/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/base.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/rizwan/Downloads/rtlwifi_new' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/rizwan/Downloads/rtlwifi_new] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic'
Makefile:87: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

i installed those modules using command

```
sudo apt install libelf-dev  libelf-devel elfutils-libelf-devel
```

only libelf-dev gets installed but remaining two is unbale to locate

```
rizwan@rizwan-HP:~$ sudo apt install libelf-dev  libelf-devel elfutils-libelf-devel
[sudo] password for rizwan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libelf-devel
E: Unable to locate package elfutils-libelf-devel
rizwan@rizwan-HP:~$
```

eventually i found that name of libraries are different-different for different linux distro so help me with installing  libelf-devel elfutils-libelf-devel in ubuntu 18.04 hp laptop ay503tx

Comment: Did you tried to run `make` (without `sudo`)?

Comment: yeahh i tried but keep getting above error

Comment: i got the same error, then i went ahead and installed just **libelf-dev** package and the problem solved somehow!!

Answer (score 2):

you need to install linix headers generic by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

I see you already have downloaded the realtek wifi drivers make sure you are in the right directory and run this to install them:

```
cd rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms add ../rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms build rtlwifi-new/0.6 
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723de ant_sel=2
```

Congrats you have running wifi.

Save the config with this command:

```
sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" >> /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf'
```

Restart.

Details here:

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-8723DE-wifi-module-amp-Bluetooth-Linux-driver/td-p/6477307

Comment: After I installed `sudo apt-get install linux-generic`, my interface device `wlo1` is disappeared. Now I cannot see any wifi. I can use only ethernet to connect to network. How to recover my interface?